# How does Scala's groupBy identity work?

Tags: scala

I was browsing around and found a question about grouping a `String` by it's characters, such as this:

The input:

```
"aaabbbccccdd"
```

Would produce the following output:

```
"aaa"
"bbb"
"cccc"
"ddd"
```

and I found this suggestion:

```
val str = "aaabbbccccdd"[
val list = str.groupBy(identity).toList.sortBy(_._1).map(_._2)
```

And this `identity` fellow got me curious. I found out it is defined in [`PreDef`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Predef%24) like this:

```
identity[A](x: A): A
```

So basically it returns whatever it is given, right? but how does that apply in the call to `groupBy`?

I'm sorry if this is a basic question, is just that functional programming is still tangling my brains a little. Please let me know if there's any information I can give to make this question clearer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To understand this just call scala repl with `-Xprint:typer` option:

```
val res2: immutable.Map[Char,String] = augmentString(str).groupBy[Char]({
   ((x: Char) => identity[Char](x))
});
```

Scalac converts a simple `String` into `StringOps` with is a subclass of `TraversableLike` which has a `groupBy` method:

```
def groupBy[K](f: A => K): immutable.Map[K, Repr] = {
    val m = mutable.Map.empty[K, Builder[A, Repr]]
    for (elem <- this) {
      val key = f(elem)
      val bldr = m.getOrElseUpdate(key, newBuilder)
      bldr += elem
    }
    val b = immutable.Map.newBuilder[K, Repr]
    for ((k, v) <- m)
      b += ((k, v.result))

    b.result
  }
```

So groupBy contains a map into which inserts chars return by identity function.

Comment: Wow, that is exactly the answer I wanted. Very specific and explanatory. Thank you very much! Thumbs up! :)

Answer (score 14):

This is your expression:

```
val list = str.groupBy(identity).toList.sortBy(_._1).map(_._2)
```

Let's go item by function by function. The first one is groupBy, which will partition your String using the list of keys passed by the discriminator function, which in your case is identity. The discriminator function will be applied to each character in the screen and all characters that return the same result will be grouped together. If we want to separate the letter a from the rest we could use `x => x == 'a'` as our discriminator function. That would group your string chars into the return of this function (true or false) in map:

```
 Map(false -> bbbccccdd, true -> aaa)
```

By using `identity`, which is a "nice" way to say `x => x`, we get a map where each character gets separated in map, in your case:

```
Map(c -> cccc, a -> aaa, d -> dd, b -> bbb)
```

Then we convert the map to a list of tuples `(char,String)`  with `toList`.

Order it by char with `sortBy` and just keep the String with the `map` getting your final result.

Answer (score 9):

First, let's see what happens when you iterate over a String:

```
scala> "asdf".toList
res1: List[Char] = List(a, s, d, f)
```

Next, consider that sometimes we want to group elements on the basis of some specific attribute of an object.

For instance, we might group a list of strings by length as in...

```
List("aa", "bbb", "bb", "bbb").groupBy(_.length)
```

What if you just wanted to group each item by the item itself.  You could pass in the identity function like this:

```
List("aa", "bbb", "bb", "bbb").groupBy(identity)
```

You could do something silly like this, but it would be silly:

```
List("aa", "bbb", "bb", "bbb").groupBy(_.toString)
```

Comment: Your first example helped me understand it better. But what I don't understand is how my `identity` that is supposed to be just like the given `String`, is turned into a `Char`

Comment: awesome explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at

```
str.groupBy(identity)
```

which returns

```
scala.collection.immutable.Map[Char,String] = Map(b -> bbb, d -> dd, a -> aaa, c -> cccc)
```

so the key by which the elements are grouped by is the character.

Comment: Yes, I understand the result, but I don't understand how the `String` itself determines that it should be grouped by character

Comment: That's an implicit conversion from `String` to `List[Char]` when you iterate over it.

Comment: Oh, so it applies the `groupBy` to each of the `Char`s because of the implicit conversion?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you try to use methods such as `groupBy` on the String. It's important to note that it is implicitly converted to [`StringOps`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.StringOps) and **not** [`List[Char]`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List).

### StringOps

The signature of `groupBy` is given by-

```
def groupBy[K](f: (Char) ⇒ K): Map[K, String]
```

Hence, the result is in the form -

```
Map[Char,String]
```

### List[Char]

The signature of `groupBy` is given by-

```
def groupBy[K](f: (Char) ⇒ K): Map[K, List[Char]]
```

If it had been implicitly converted to [`List[Char]`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List) the result would be of the form -

```
Map[Char,List[Char]]
```

Now this should implicitly answer your curious question, as how scala figured out to `groupBy` on `Char` (see the signature) and yet give you `Map[Char, String]`.

Comment: Very interesting point. But how would I know exactly what it does? Does it group by each individual char in the `String`, avoiding repetitions?

Answer (score 0):

Basically list.groupBy(identity) is just a fancy way of saying list.groupBy(x => x), which in my opinion is clearer. It groups a list containing duplicate items by those items.