# Scala process lists of string and produce Map["Combination",Count of Lists with that combination]

Tags: list, scala, dictionary, consolidation

I have a Seq[List[String]]. Example :

```
Vector(
["B","D","A","P","F"], 
["B","A","F"], 
["B","D","A","F"], 
["B","D","A","T","F"], 
["B","A","P","F"], 
["B","D","A","P","F"], 
["B","A","F"], 
["B","A","F"], 
["B","A","F"], 
["B","A","F"]
)
```

I would like to get the count of different combinations (like "A","B") in a Map[String,Int] where the key (String) is the element combinations and value (Int) is the count of Lists having this combinations. 
 
 If "A" and "B" and "F" are appearing in all the 10 records, instead of having "A", 10 and "B", 10 and "C", 10 would like to consolidate that into ""A","B","F"" , 10

Sample (not all combinations included) result for the above Seq[List[String]]

```
Map(
""A","B","F"" -> 10,
""A","B","D"" -> 4,
""A","B","P"" -> 2,
...
...
..
)
```

Would appreciate if I can be given any scala code / solution to get this  output.

Comment: Does every key have to be the concatenation of 3 strings? Not interested in 2 or 4 string combinations? Why include all the quote marks and commas in each key? Why not `"ABF"` or `"A,B,F"` instead of `"\"A\",\"B\",\"F\""`?

Comment: if you say `Seq[List[String]]` the example of the data should be: 
Seq(
      List("B","D","A","P","F"),
      List("B","A","F"),
      List("B","D","A","F"),
      List("B","D","A","T","F"),
      List("B","A","P","F"),
      List("B","D","A","P","F"),
      List("B","A","F"),
      List("B","A","F"),
      List("B","A","F"),
      List("B","A","F")
    )

Answer (score 1):

The format of your vector is not correct scala syntax, which I think you mean something like this:

```
val items = Seq(
  Seq("B", "D", "A", "P", "F"),
  Seq("B", "A", "F"),
  Seq("B", "D", "A", "F"),
  Seq("B", "D", "A", "T", "F"),
  Seq("B", "A", "P", "F"),
  Seq("B", "D", "A", "P", "F"),
  Seq("B", "A", "F"),
  Seq("B", "A", "F"),
  Seq("B", "A", "F"),
  Seq("B", "A", "F")
)
```

It sounds like what you are trying to accomplish is two `group by` clauses. First, you would like to get all combinations from each list, then get the most frequent combinations accross the sets, get how often they occur, and then for groups that occur at the same frequency, do another `group by` and merge those together.

For this you will need the following function to perform the double reduction after the double groupby.

Steps:

1. Collect all the sequences of groups. Inside items, we calculate the total combinations of elements inside that list of items which generates a `Seq[Seq[String]]` of groups where the `Seq[String]` is a unique combination. This is flattened because the `(1 to group.length)` operation generates a `Seq` of `Seq[Seq[String]]`. We then flatten all the mappings together accross all the lists in the vector you have to get a `Seq[Seq[String]]`
2. The `groupMapReduce` function is used to calculate how often a certain combination appears, and then each combination is given a value of 1 to be summed up. This gives a frequency on how often any certain combination shows up.
3. The groups are grouped again, but this time by the number of occurences. So if "A" and "B" both occur 10 times, they will be grouped together.
4. The final map reduces the groups that were accumulated

```
val combos = items.flatMap(group => (1 to group.length).flatMap(i => group.combinations(i).map(_.sorted)).distinct) // Seq[Seq[String]]
  .groupMapReduce(identity)(_ => 1)(_ + _)  // Map[Seq[String, Int]]
  .groupMapReduce(_._2)(v => Seq(v))(_ ++ _) // Map[Int, Seq[(Seq[String], Int)]]
  .map { case (total, groups) => (groupReduction(groups), total)} // reduction function to determine how you want to double reduce these groups.
```

This double reduction function I've defined as follows. It converted a group like `Seq("A","B")` into `""A","B""` and then if `Seq("A","B")` has the same count as another `group Seq("C")`, then the group is concatenated together as `""A","B"","C""`

```
def groupReduction(groups: Seq[(Seq[String], Int)]): String = {
  groups.map(_._1.map(v => s"""$v""").sorted.mkString(",")).sorted.mkString(",")
}
```

This filter can be adjusted for particular groups of interest in the `(1 to group.length)` clause. If limited from `3 to 3`, then the groups would be

```
List(List(B, D, P), List(A, D, P), List(D, F, P)): 2
List(List(A, B, F)): 10
List(List(B, D, F), List(A, D, F), List(A, B, D)): 4
List(List(A, F, P), List(B, F, P), List(A, B, P)): 3
List((List(B, D, T), List(A, F, T), List(B, F, T), List(A, D, T), List(A, B, T), List(D, F, T)): 1

As you can see in your example, `List(B, D, F)` and `List(A, D, F)` are also associated with your second line "A,B,D".
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data with different order counted as one group, e.g: BAF, and ABF will be in one group, the solution would be.

```
          //define the data
          val a = Seq(
            List("B","D","A","P","F"),
            List("B","A","F"),
            List("B","D","A","F"),
            List("B","D","A","T","F"),
            List("B","A","P","F"),
            List("B","D","A","P","F"),
            List("B","A","F"),
            List("B","A","F"),
            List("B","A","F"),
            List("A","B","F")
          )

          //you need to sorted so B,A,F will be counted as the same as A,B,F
          //as all other data with different sequence
          val b = a.map(_.sorted)

          //group by identity, and then count the length
          b.groupBy(identity).collect{case (x, y) => (x, y.length)}
```

the output will be like this:

```
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[List[String],Int] = HashMap(List(A, B, F, P) -> 1, List(A, B, D, F) -> 1, List(A, B, D, F, T) -> 1, List(A, B, D, F, P) -> 2, List(A, B, F) -> 5)
```

to understand more about how Scala's groupBy identity works, you can go to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19165977/how-does-scalas-groupby-identity-work)

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
scala> def count(seq: Seq[Seq[String]]): Map[Seq[String], Int] =
     |   seq.flatMap(_.toSet.subsets.filter(_.nonEmpty)).groupMapReduce(identity)(_ => 1)(_ + _)
     |      .toSeq.sortBy(-_._1.size).foldLeft(Map.empty[Set[String], Int]){ case (r, (p, i)) =>
     |        if(r.exists{ (q, j) => i == j && p.subsetOf(q)}) r else r.updated(p, i)
     |      }.map{ case(k, v) => (k.toSeq, v) }
def count(seq: Seq[Seq[String]]): Map[Seq[String], Int]

scala> count(Seq(
     |   Seq("B", "D", "A", "P", "F"),
     |   Seq("B", "A", "F"),
     |   Seq("B", "D", "A", "F"),
     |   Seq("B", "D", "A", "T", "F"),
     |   Seq("B", "A", "P", "F"),
     |   Seq("B", "D", "A", "P", "F"),
     |   Seq("B", "A", "F"),
     |   Seq("B", "A", "F"),
     |   Seq("B", "A", "F"),
     |   Seq("B", "A", "F")
     | ))
val res1: Map[Seq[String], Int] = 
  HashMap(List(F, A, B) -> 10, 
          List(F, A, B, P, D) -> 2, 
          List(T, F, A, B, D) -> 1, 
          List(F, A, B, D) -> 4, 
          List(F, A, B, P) -> 3)
```

As you can see, the "A, B, D" and "A, B, P" are reduced in the result, since the are subset of "ABDF" and "ABPDF" ...